# Android making a listview with numbered items

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I want to make a dynamic ListView with numbered items. Here I have retrieved values from SQLite database into the ListView and actually it is numbered according to their id's which are stored in database. But I'm using a dynamic list view, so I want to show numbered items starting from 1 in each time I load the ListView. For example people booking flight tickets for different dates and flight authorities will display a final ListView for the current date including persons who booked for that date.

```
 consider today is 10-12-2014
 person A booked ticket for the date 12-12-2014, so his "id" might be "1" in database.
 person B booked ticket for the date 13-12-2014,so his "id" might be "2" in database.
 person c booked ticket for the date 13-12-2014,so his "id" might be "3" in database.


    but when the day "13-12-2014" comes person B's id should be "1"(no need to have any connection with database, just enough a numberd representation to   show today's list is this. 

like 
 1.person B
 2.person C

  thats all.
```

This is my displayadapter class:

```
 public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> id;
private ArrayList<String>name;
private ArrayList<String>phone;


public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id,ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> phone) {
    this.mContext = c;

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return id.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewthem, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.d);
        mHolder.txt_name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.nm);
        mHolder.txt_phone = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.ph);
        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_name.setText(name.get(pos));
    mHolder.txt_phone.setText(phone.get(pos));

    return child;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView txt_id;
    TextView txt_name;
    TextView txt_phone;
}


}
```

This is my dbhelper class:

```
    mydb = new DBhelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase database = mydb.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE dt='"+d+"'", null);

        userId.clear();
        user_name.clear();
        user_phone.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID)));
                user_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
                user_phone.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(token.this,userId, user_name, user_phone);

        obj.setAdapter(disadpt);
        disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mCursor.close();
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but if I got it right, won't `mHolder.txt_id.setText(pos + 1)` work?

Comment: sorry its getting error.please look at my example to question get cleared please

Comment: just putting number from(1-number of items available in that listview) infront of listview items,but here the items are coming from database that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the list to simply be numbered (as you said, without regard to the actual IDs in the database) you simply need to use the `pos` parameter you receive in `getView()`. And you'd probably want to use `pos + 1` so the list will be 1-based (more user friendly).

Assuming `mHolder.txtId` is the TextView you want to use to display the numbers, as I said in my comment, this should work:

```
mHolder.txt_id.setText(String.valueOf(pos + 1));
```

If you get an error when trying this please explain exactly what error.

Comment: but when i did like that my list view getting invisible,please tell me what are the other places to make changes in my program

Comment: Well, for once you should inflate the view like so: `child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewthem, parent, false);`

Comment: sorry sir logcat error W/ResourceType(1748): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001,here how i can  block value of id retrieving from database

Comment: mHolder.txt_id.setText(""+ (pos + 1) + ". ");,but this code is worked for me instead of that thank you.You saved my time